# Copying data from one sheet to another column automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function copyData() {
  
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('TOTAL_ORDERS_DATA');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();


  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Data Archive');
  let lastColumn = targetSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
  
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(lastColumn,11, rowCount,columnCount);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);

}
```

so basically I will need to copy the data from the source sheet to the next available column in the target sheet, I can understand that that lastcolumn need to be + 1, but what's happeninng right now is just it's replacing the value in the targetRange instead of posting it to the next free column

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you want

Comment: Take a look at [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and how to use them. It's pretty simple, provided your current code already works as intended.

Comment: bascially I have a source sheet that automatically refreshes data everyday, I have used IMPORTRANGE to copy a specific column from the source sheet to a blank sheet, then I need to copy the data in the blank sheet to the targetSheet everyday, but I need to add the copied data to another column everyday in the tragetSheet as the sourcesheet refreshes? I hope that makes sense..

Comment: @RodrigoBiffi it does work, however it replaces the data's in column (3,11) instead of pasting it to the next one available column

Comment: You're not using `lastRowCount` for anything, and when you set `targetRange` to receive the fix range (3, 11), that's exactly what you'll get every single time.  Try using the same method to get the last column + 1 (which would be the next blank one, as for the rows), and use those variables as range arguments on `targetRange`.

Comment: @RodrigoBiffi how would I get the lastColumnCount + 1 to reiterate? sorr I am new to this and still trying to capture the logic..

Comment: @Jove - Could you provide sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function copyData() {
  
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Reference (do not edit)');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();


  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Data Archive');
  let lastrowCount = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  let lastColumnCount = targetSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
  
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,lastColumnCount, rowCount,columnCount);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Comment: Is this a solution? Or more information about your question? Please clarify by adding some explanation. If it's supporting information for your original question, please edit it into your original question and delete this as an answer.

Comment: this is the answer